# itpp soft demodulation

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the output of the soft demapper function (demodulate_soft_bits) when using 16-QAM and 64-QAM modulation.
here is a portion of the code (64-QAM):

```
 cvec comple; 
Modulator_2D qam; 
ivec cont_d = "0:1:63";
vec qam_r = "-7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -5 -5 -5 -5  -5 -5 -5 -5 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 1  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 5  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7";
vec qam_i = "-7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7 -7 -5 -3 -1   1  3  5  7 -7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7 -7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7 -7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5 7 -7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7 -7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5 7 -7 -5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7";
comple.set_length(qam_i.length(),false); 
for(int i=0; i<qam_i.length(); i++)
comple(i) = std::complex<double>(qam_r(i)/sqrt((double)42),qam_i(i)/sqrt((double)42));
qam.set(comple, cont_d);  
temp = qam.demodulate_soft_bits( symb_recus,channel,1);
```

symb_recus is the output of a realistic 4x4 MIMO channel

channel is the channel gain

At the output I got a random values which doesn't correspond to the hard output and I got also a succession of 0
exp :

```
temp :        [6.80 3.33 1.64 -14.27 -7.06 -3.51 0 0 0 0 0 0 -3.47 .....]
Hard output : [  0   1    0       1    1     1   1 1 0 0 1 1   0    ... ]
```

can you please help me

Comment: When the Stack Exchange software prohibited you from writing _"problem"_ in the title, the hope was that you would write a better title, not "trick" the system by introducing a deliberate typo. Very clever.

Comment: I didn't know that using the word "Probelm" in the title is prohibited.

Comment: Oh it was just a typo then. lol okay.